# Cannot connect my Moto X to Windows 7 PC

Tags: usb, connection-issues, usb-connection-mode, usb-drivers, moto-x

I cannot connect my Moto X to Windows 7, 32-bit PC via USB. After doing some research normal solutions people found were

1. Enabling MTP in connection settings.
2. Disabling USB debugging in Dev. settings.
3. Updating drivers.
4. Updating windows media player.

I've tried all of this still my PC can't detect Moto X as USB storage device. It shows the device in - Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers, but says this device does not work properly as Windows cannot load its drivers. It gives option to re install drivers in troubleshooting but everytime I do it the device driver is not successfully installed.

[image: Here's the snapshot of the errors]

Comment: https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/94931/p/30,6720,8696/action/auth try installing this

Comment: @sameer I've already installed it... Even tried re installing it several times still it doesn't work.

Comment: Goto device manager and right click on the motorola device name and select `Update Driver Software` and click browse and point to the driver location.

Comment: It says device driver is already installed... @sameer

Comment: 1. connect your phone with computer
2. go to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Motorola Shared\Mobile Drivers\
3. run Motorola Driver Installer.exe, choose clean and Reinstall.

Comment: That is not helping either... @sameer

Comment: It should work. Try in different port or in different pc

Comment: it works in other PC without even installing drivers it automatically installs drivers from windows 7 database in other PC... the problem is with this PC only..

Comment: Take a look at [this question/answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/93168/android-5-0-lollipop-device-not-detected-via-usb). The device is different and the drivers are too, but the method should be the same.

Answer (score 6):

If your phone is able to connect in another PC, the problem is in PC and not with the droid. The possible solutions are

1. Download [Motorola driver](https://motorola-global-portal.custhelp.com/app/answers/prod_answer_detail/a_id/94931/p/30,6720,8696/action/auth)
2. Goto Device Manager and right click on the motorola device name and select uninstall
3. Now right click and select `Scan Hardware Change` Now select `Update Driver Software` and click browse and point to the downloaded driver location

**If this does not work Try:**

1. connect your phone with computer
2. go to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Motorola Shared\Mobile Drivers\`
3. Run `Motorola Driver Installer.exe`, choose `clean` and `Reinstall`.

**or**

The problem may be due to windows mtp driver and you can try the [fix](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn614016%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) provided by Microsoft.

**or**

1. Unistall driver from device manager
2. Remove all USB controllers
3. Disable Windows Media Player (`Control Panel - Uninstall a program - Turn Windows features on or off - Expand Media Feature - Uncheck Windows Media Player`)
4. Connect your device and Reboot the pc
5. Reactivate Windows Media Player(`Control Panel - Uninstall a program - Turn Windows features on or off - Expand Media Feature - Check Windows Media Player`)

Comment: I formatted C drive and reinstalled windows.. And now it works without installing drivers too... thanks for the help though...

Answer (score 2):

OK, I pulled my hair out for almost 2-days.  I'd install the Moto USB driver ware on my PC (Moto Device Mgr V2.5.4) and when I'd connect my Moto X via USB, the driver wouldn't 'install' properly.  Status via Cntl Panel, Device & Printer, showed a device named XT1095 (yep that's my Moto X) but flagged with a yellow exclamation point and the declaration 'Driver Not Installed'.

After a NUMBER of uninstall/re-install episodes and delving into the Moto X (turn developer USB options ON/OFF), I tried the setup on my older Dell laptop.  BINGO, everything worked like a hose!  Hey, what's the difference?

Well, one thing is the Dell hardware is specifically limited to USB 2.0.  My desktop PC running a quad core based motherboard has both USB 2.0 and 3.0 ports on it.  Hum...

I did a clean install of the Moto Device Mgr and then connected my unlocked/running Moto X intentionally to a USB 2.0 port.  KAZOOM, the device driver installed and all was working!  Then, I unplugged the Android phone and re-installed it on a USB 3.0 port where it had previously failed to work. VAROOM, it came up and running nicely!

Methinks there's an issue here of technical due diligence in testing the Moto USB driver with various hardware manufacturer specific USB ports...

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried unlocking your screen after plugging in the USB cable?

I was having a similar issue - my Moto X would charge but not connect as media device - but none of the above advice was relevant. Finally, I realized that it would not connect as long as the screen was locked. After entering my PIN, it connected immediately. In retrospect, this is a really obvious security feature! Just thought I'd post this in case someone else has also misdiagnosed this as a USB issue.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem with my moto e and windows 7 professional, XP i.e. unable to connect.

Earlier, it did connect with every system but for the last few days it did not.
Today an IT person gave me another USB cable (thicker one) and it worked.

Comment: +1 for the suggestion. After researching different USB cables at http://www.cablestogo.com/learning/connector-guides/usb , swapping the USB cable from "Micro-USB A" to "Micro-USB B" solved the problem. The "Micro-USB A" cable did not work because Windows recognized the phone as a generic usb device. On the other hand, both Windows and Motorola Device Manager see the phone correctly when using the "Micro-USB B" cable.

Answer (score 1):

Okay this is extremely weird, but I've found this with more than one laptop (one HP and one Acer). For some reason the second USB port from the front of laptop never works with certain devices. My 3G dongle and now my Moto X would not be detected properly and said 'unrecognized device'. I had the same issues as the original question, but after switching ports it just works, every time. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

To make a Moto G device work with Windows 7 computers, go to Settings > Developer options on the device and select USB configuration. Change it to PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol) instead of MTP (Media Transfer Protocol). 
I have been racking my brains and searching the phone and web for answers. Poking around the phone did it! Good luck :)

Answer (score -2):

Had the same problem and nothing worked until I made sure I was using a USB data cable. Maybe the one I was using is for charging only

Comment: This doesn't really answer or attempts to answer the question. OP clearly mentioned that (s)he tried changing USB connection (MTP, USB debugging) which IMO cannot be done if the cable is for charging only.